# Why does the session becomes unavailable in another script?

Tags: javascript, php

I have two scripts. One say welcome.php and page.php

In welcome.php I have say

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(4));

$val = $_SESSION['test'];

$reply = ['data'=> $val];

exit (json_encode($reply));
```

In page.php, I have..

```
session_start();

$val = $_POST['test']//this is the value of $_SESSION['test'] in welcome.php

If($val === $_SESSION['test']){

echo 'yes';

}
```

I first sent ajax request to welcome.php to get the session test value then again I need to send request to page.php with the data gotten from welcome.php and use at page.php but its giving an error that $_SESSION['test'] is an undefined array key which means  the $_SESSION['test'] is not defined but it was set in welcome.php.

I really don't know what else to set but I tried ensuring I got a value from welcome.php by doing this.

```
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

My header is also set to allow request from the origin am sending it from.

**UPDATE**

I checked to see if same session id was used for the two requests and discovered it was different so I changed my ajax request to this in order to make subsequent request use the same session id

```
const id = window.localStorage.getItem("id");//the session id gotten from first ajax request



$.ajax({

      url:url,
      method:'post',
      xhrFields:{
        withCredentials:true
      },
      headers: {
    /*'Content-Type': 'application/json',*/
    'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken,
    'x-session-id':id,
  },
      dataType:'json',
      data:input,
      success: function(r){
//updateLoginStatus()

 if( r.status === 1 ){
   
   props.setIsLogged(true)

 }

else{

  showAlert(r.msg,"error")
}
        setBtnLoading(false);


  props.setCsrf(r.token);


      },
      error:function(a){
//console.log(a)
        setBtnLoading(false)

     
      }
      
      
    })
```

However, the ajax requests fails to go through. If I comment out the header part, then it will go but then different session is used and can't still access previous session value stored.

What could be the problem

Comment: also `If($val === $_SESSION['test']){` is not going to succeed anyway as `$_POST['test']` is seems like coming from form and has no encryption done. while `$_SESSION['test']` has some encrypted data

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant $_SESSION['test'] is  even undefined that's where the error is

Comment: How specifically are you sending these requests?  Sessions are often tracked by a cookie value, is that being included in the requests?  If the requests are AJAX requests made from a web page, is the first one being awaited before sending the second one?

Comment: _"My header is also set to allow request from the origin am sending it from"_ - so this is a cross-origin request? Then you most likely neglected to specify that _credentials_ should be sent along with this request. That does not happen by default for cross-origin background requests, and cookies are part of what is considered "credentials". And if your request does not include the cookie that transports the session ID, then your receiving script won't be able to pick up any existing session, but will start a new, _empty_ one.

Comment: I tried including the session in the request and getting it via get like this $id = $_GET['I'd]; session_id($id); session_start(); but also error that I can't change existing session

Comment: @CBroe how do I do that pls

Comment: You have not told us what you are using to make your AJAX request (native XMLHttpRequest, $.ajax, fetch, ...), but basically, you need to set the `withCredentials` flag to true. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: Am using jquery ajax

Comment: @Eduty When you place `var_dump(session_id());` in your php scripts and call them, do you get the same session id or different ids?